# Laravel - How to check if date is already exists?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

There is my table:

```
- fortress -
   - id - 
   - date -
```

In my case I just want to check:

```
if ($date > Carbon::today())
{
     // Create a record
}
```

Then I want only one record to create and I need to check something like this:

```
if ($date > Carbon::today() && and exists)
{

}
```

Just I know how to check if the date is greater than today. But now when I press button 2 times it creates two record. I need to check if the date is greater than today and if it's already exists.

Comment: You can query your table and check if that date is already exists or not

Comment: Where is `$date` coming from? Is this an input field?

Comment: Yea. It's input field in my api

Answer (score 1):

This is the coding I wrote to see if the user name is saved in the user table in advance. If you want to check many more data

```
->where('userName',$request->userName)
```

Add in this where condition.

**Controllers code**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Hash;
    
    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function alreadyExistUserName(Request $request) {
            $user = DB::table('user')
            ->where('userName',$request->userName)
            ->first();
    
            if($user === null )
                return response()->json('false', 200);
            else
                return response()->json('true', 200);
        }  
    }
```

**API code**

```
Route::post('alreadyExistUserName', 'UserController@alreadyExistUserName');
```

In this case, you are posting data to will get the output as "False" if you have data in already and not "True".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel validation if you use $request object :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'date' => 'required|unique:your_table|date|after:now',
    // ... other validation rules
]);
```

Or you can simply use a query :

```
$dateExists = YourModel::where('date', $date)->first();

if ($dateExists) {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel validations

```
 'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:3',
                Rule::unique('products')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('store_id', $store_id);
                })->whereNull('deleted_at'),                
            ],
```